# Proving an inequality with logs and L'Hopital Rule

Tags: inequality, logarithms

I have the following inequality that I am trying to prove:

$log_2n < 2*(log_2n)^{1/2}$

${log_2n \over 2*(log_2n)^{1/2}} < 1$

I am trying to find a value N1 > 0 so that the inequality is true for all n > N1.

My approach is to use L'Hopital's rule so that if I can show that $\lim_{x\to ∞} f'(n)/g'(n)  = 0$ then the inequality will hold.

$\lim_{x\to ∞} f(n)/g(n) = ∞/∞$, so L'Hopital's rule can be used.

However, using L'Hopital's rule I have got:

$\lim_{x\to ∞} f'(n)/g'(n) = {{1 \over nlog2}/{1\over n*(log2)^{1/2}*(logn)^{1/2}}} = {1/∞ \over 1/∞}$ = 0/0

which is of indeterminate form.

What are some other ways that I can prove the inequality?

Comment: The inequality.... will not be true. You are trying to prove $\sqrt{\log_2 n} < 2$ for all $n\geq N_1$? But the LHS tends to infinity...

Answer (score 1):

The inequality is not true. In fact, $\log_2(x) > 2(\log_2(x))^\frac{1}{2}$ for all $x > 16$.